# left regular representation of $Q_8$

Tags: group-theory

**Q.** Use the left regular representation of $Q_8$ to produce two elements of $S_8$ which generate subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $Q_8$.

Can any one please explain this solution?

Since $Q_8 = \langle i,j\rangle$

Now 
$$i(1) = i, \,\,\,\, i(-1) = -i, \,\,\,\, i(i) = -1,\,\,\,\, i(-i) = 1,$$ $$ i(j) = k,\,\,\,\,  i(-j)= -k,\,\,\,\,  i(k) = -j,\,\,\,\, i(-k) = j.$$ 
Thus  $i \mapsto (1, i, -1, -i)(j, k, -j, -k)$

Similarly, 
$$j(1) = j,\,\,\,\,j(-1) = -j,\,\,\,\,j(i) = -k,\,\,\,\, j(-i) = k,$$
$$j(j) = -1,\,\,\,\, j(-j) = -1,\,\,\,\, j(k) = i,\,\,\,\, j(-k) = -i.$$ 
Thus $j\mapsto (1, j, -1, -j)(i, -k, -i, k).$

With the labeling
$1 \mapsto 1,\,\,\,\, -1 \mapsto 2,  \,\,\,\,i \mapsto 3,\,\,\,\,-i \mapsto 4,\,\,\,\, j \mapsto 5, \,\,\,\, -j \mapsto 6,\,\,\,\,  k \mapsto 7,-k \mapsto 8$

we have $Q_8$ isomorphic $\langle (1, 3, 2, 4)(5, 7, 6, 8), (1, 5, 2, 6)(3, 8, 4, 7)\rangle$

Comment: You mean for every $x$ in $Q_8$. Then $f(g) \in S_8$.

Comment: plz post a answer.

Comment: Two hints: (1) You have to identify the symmetric group on the set $Q_8$ with $S_8$ (which works since $Q_8$ has $8$ elements). (2) If you know two elements $x, y$ of $Q_8$ that generate $Q_8$ (i.e., $\langle x, y\rangle = Q_8$, then their images under your $f$ will generate a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $Q_8$.

Comment: @j.p. plz see the edit..

Comment: The two permutations you have written down do indeed generte a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $Q_8$. So you've done it!

Comment: What do you mean with "Can any one please explain this solution?"? Where does the solution come from and which steps do you not understand?